# Cannot access class 'android.widget.fragment'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android, fragment

I have fragment and inside it I have child fragment. I can't access from parent fragment using binding cos it gives compilation error. I did like this:

From parent fragment, I did:

```
val fragment = binding.calculatorSheetHome // calculatorSheetHome is fragment id
```

But compile error says,

```
Cannot access class 'android.widget.fragment'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

1. Here is  parent fragment layout code, and I am trying to access `calculator_sheet_home`

   ```
    <variable
        name="mLanguage"
        type="com.hamidjonhamidov.calculator.model.room.LanguageM" />
   ```

   ```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutFullscreen="@{true}">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/grid_0_25"
            app:paddingBottomSystemWindowInsets="@{true}"
            app:paddingTopSystemWindowInsets="@{true}"
            android:clipToPadding="false">


            // ... 
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/calculator_sheet_home"
        android:name="com.hamidjonhamidov.calculator.ui.main.home.calculator_sheet_home.CalculatorSheetFragmentHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragment is not "View" so you cannot access it like traditional view. But, you can access it via fragment tag doing like this:

```
<fragment
     android:id="@+id/calculator_sheet_home"
     android:name="com.hamidjonhamidov.calculator.ui.main.home.calculator_sheet_home.CalculatorSheetFragmentHome"
     android:tag="fragment_sheet_home" // add this line
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Now from parent fragment you can do this:

```
val childFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment_sheet_home") as? CalculatorSheetFragmentHome ?: return
```

Now, you can use your fragment for whatever reason)

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me,note i was using Bottom Nav and View Binding

```
val childFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment_sheet_home") as? NavHostFragment
```